# define three functions into one in python

Tags: python

I have defined these functions in python :

```
def Density(rho0,r,Rc,Rd):

   if r < Rc :
   return  rho0 

   elif r> Rc :
   return rho0*np.exp(-(r-Rc)/Rd) 

def Thickness_H(H0,r,Rh):   
    return H0*np.exp(r/Rh)
```

Now I want to use these two functions to write the final equation using these two functions:

The new function looks like this (I don't know how I can put the first and second functions into the function below):

```
def Density_distribution(H0,Rh,r,z,rho0,Rc,Rd):

      return firstfunction*np.exp(-z/secondfunction)
```

and plot it:

```
r = np.linspace(0.,10., 100) 
p =Density_distribution(H0,Rh,r,z,rho0,Rc,Rd)
plt.plot(r, p)
plt.show()
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You have to *call* the functions (with the appropriate arguments). Just like you do for the third function.

Comment: So what's wrong with *just using the functions*? What happened when you, say, replaced `firstfunction` with `Density(rho0, r, Rc, Rd)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the functions to get their return value in any statement:

```py
def Density_distribution(H0, Rh, r, z, rho0, Rc, Rd):
      return Density(rho0, r, Rc, Rd) * np.exp(-z / Thickness_H(H0, r, Rh))
```

Or in case you receive the `rho0` parameter as string in `Density_distribution`, just convert it to a `float` before calling the `Density` function:

```py
def Density_distribution(H0, Rh, r, z, rho0, Rc, Rd):
      return Density(float(rho0), r, Rc, Rd) * np.exp(-z / Thickness_H(H0, r, Rh))
```

Comment: thank you. one more thing if I want to plot each functions, the values of all parameters is fixed number except r, then I think I have to defined r something like as I defined it above and plot it is this correct?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking, Python does not use any fixed data type assignments but duck typing. So it does not matter what data type you pass as argument to this function as long as the function internally can operate with those data types. Also, please do not forget to accept this answer by clicking the grey tick symbol on the left if it solves your problem.

Comment: I mean: the parameter value are : H0 =0.06, Rc =7, Rd =3.15 ,rho0=3e-11.      if I want to plot these function who can I do this?

Comment: Simply convert that string `rho0="3e-11"` into a floating point decimal number using `rho0 = float(rho0)`.

Comment: Why did you unaccept the answer?

Comment: sorry, last question when I define r= r = np.linspace(0.,10., 100)  to plot one of these function I got error :only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with NumPy. You could ask that as separate question.